# How would I go about several contract values among various monthly start and end dates in Excel? Would like to use one dynamic formula if possible

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

How would I go about several contract values among various monthly start and end dates in Excel? Would like to use one dynamic formula if possible

I've tried playing around with it and have come up with this formula so far but the sum of the months doesn't exactly add up given that there aren't 30 days in every month

```
=($E2<=H$1)*(H$1<=$F2)*($D2/(($F2-$E2)/30))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question it is unclear what you are trying to "go about". As is, this question should be closed.

Comment: What are you trying to determine using your formula?

Comment: From your formula it looks like you're trying to pick out the records that start before and end after the date in cell `H1` and then get a daily Contract value?  Is that per record or do you want some kind of summary?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a specific number of months and dividing total days by 30 isn’t precise enough for your use case.

If you want to get precise I’d suggest using the YEAR() and MONTH() functions on the dates.  The math would be cumbersome but not complicated.  Basically `(YEAR(F2)-YEAR(E2))*12 + (MONTH(F2)-MONTH(F1))`

Alternatively I sometimes do something more like MONTH(F2-E2) and see if that gets me the result I wanted, but I am careful to check for unpredicted reasults.

If you are trying to do something like precise journal entries for *very* large accruals, you still have to think about how to handle partial months.